# Inverse mapping of numpy.sort

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I want to get an index for the inverse mapping of np.sort

In other words, if I have a code

```
x=[[4,3],[2,3],[4,2]]
ind1=np.lexsort((x[:,1],x[:,0]))
y=x[ind1] #y=[[2,3],[4,2],[4,3]]
```

then I want an index such that

```
y[ind]
```

returns the original function x.
Is there any way to get this index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.argsort` on `ind1`:

```
idx = np.argsort(ind1)
y[idx]
# array([[4, 3],
#        [2, 3],
#        [4, 2]])
```